# Convert char to string in OCaml

Tags: string, char, type-conversion, ocaml

I want to convert a char to a string but I haven't found a function `string_of_char`. I want to do that using only functions from Pervasives.

Comment: I really suggest you to learn ocaml formally, here is a most recent best book on it and its html version is free: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html

Comment: It is not possible to do so only using functions from Pervasives, and the accepted answer does not respect this constraint, so it would be better to edit it out of the question (along with the "Thanks for you help", which does not fit the SO guidelines). If you meant "from the default standard library", then the answer using `String.make` would be fine. If you mean "using some standard library", then the one using Core is also fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Core, you can write

```
open Core.Std

let s = Char.to_string 's'
```

Answer (score 44):

You can use String.make :)

```
String.make 1 mychar
```

Comment: I said I want to use only functions from Pervasives

Comment: There is no such function in Pervasives. Just read the manual.

Comment: People down vote without thinking! Why you down vote me in this case?

Comment: You are asking very many questions that you should be able to answer with very little research on your own. This isn't a good use of StackOverflow in my opinion (and probably the ones who vote you down--not me in this case FWIW).

Comment: I have searched and I found the solution given by rafix but I was searching for function from Pervasives.

Comment: Why? The String module is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 7):

Another one you can use:

```
Char.escaped 'a'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want any dependencies outside the standard library that ships with OCaml*, you can also convert a character to a string using a format string.

Create a 1-character string out of a character

```
Printf.sprintf "%c" ch
```

(note that capital `C`) Create a string containing the OCaml notation for the given character

```
Printf.sprintf "%C" ch
```

for example:

```
# Printf.sprintf "%C" '\\';;
- : string = "'\\\\'"
# Printf.sprintf "%C" 'a';;
- : string = "'a'"
```

*`Printf` is not itself part of `Pervasives`